# Why Can't I Use Output Binding In Azure Function When Triggered by a Timer?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub

I have an azure c# http trigger function which I'm using to insert data into Azure Table Storage and an Event Hub which works perfectly as I'd expect:

```
[FunctionName("MyAzureHttpFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("TheTableName")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputTable,
            [EventHub("theeventhub", Connection="EventHubConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputEvents,
            ILogger log)
        {
            TheData myData = new TheData {*Set some properties*};

            await outputTable.AddAsync(myData);
            await outputEvents.AddAsync(myData);

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"All Done!");
        }
```

However when I create an Azure Function with a timer trigger the bindings don't seem to work within the same project / App Service. I don't get any errors but no data goes into the table or event hub. Any ideas what I need to do to allow this to work?

```
public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("*/3 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,                    
                [Table("TheTableName")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputTable,
                [EventHub("theeventhub", Connection="EventHubConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputEvents,
                ILogger log)
            {
                TheData myData = new TheData {*Set some properties*};

                await outputTable.AddAsync(myData);
                await outputEvents.AddAsync(myData);        
            }
```

Comment: Where is your connection string for table? Or you want it to write to same blob storage as your AF?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Thanks for Matt Brooke's contribution, I update his efforts of this question. When you face this strange problem, for the event hub not work, please check your vpn/firewall. For the table not work, please check if there was a schema issue of your table storage, you can choose to drop the table and allowed it to re-create to solve this problem.

**Original Answer:**

I think if the binding can works on httptrigger, then it can works on timetrigger.

By the way, you don't have a connection string in table output binding. And if you don't return Task, please use no-async method.

You can have a check, below is my code and it works:

**Function2.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp94
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async void Run([TimerTrigger("*/3 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
            [Table("TheTableName", Connection = "str")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputTable,
            [EventHub("theeventhub", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<TheData> outputEvents,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            TheData myData = new TheData { PartitionKey = rand.Next(1,1000000000).ToString(), RowKey = rand.Next(1, 1000000000).ToString(), Test = "This is the time now: "+DateTime.Now };
            log.LogInformation(myData.Test + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            await outputTable.AddAsync(myData);
            await outputEvents.AddAsync(myData);
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "str": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "EventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://testbowman.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=testbowman;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx;EntityPath=theeventhub"
  }
}
```

**TheData.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp94
{
    public class TheData
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

[image]

Any update please let me know.:)

Comment: Many thanks for your response, it gave me the impetus to try a few things which have resolved my issue albeit indirectly. It seems as though my VPN / firewall was causing the problem with the event hub not working and it was a schema issue for the table storage (dropped the table and allowed it to re-create to solve that). Many thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @MattBrooke Hi, MattBrooke. Thank for your contribution! I have update your efforts 
 of this question in my answer. Maybe you can mark it as the answer of this question. This will help others who meet this strange problem.:)